# Keep perspective configurations in new instance of Ecplise

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, when I use the Window->New Window command, a new instance of Eclipse is opened using the same workspace. However, only one perspective is available in the toolbar (they remain available through the menus) and the configuration of every perspective (which views are displayed and where) is reset to the default values.

Is there a way to retain the perspective configurations in a new instance of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can save perspective configurations in Window->Save Perspective As. Once the perspective is saved, the New Window command uses these saved settings in the new window.